# Create Facebook share button, without automatic customization

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm creating my own Facebook button by using the following istructions:

http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-create-your-one-facebook-share-url/

However my title and meta-information is replaced by the information automatically fetched by Facebook.

In other words, the description I append using `&t=<title of content>`, is replaced by Facebook with the automatically retrieved page title.

How can I disable this ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the open graph tags... http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: @Adam Holmes Uhm, could you give me a more detailed answer ? I know such documentation page. I'm trying to create multiple facebook buttons with the title of each section of my page

Comment: Patrick, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. How parameter &t works. 
If Facebook is unable to reach the page, then it will use the "t" parameter instead.  So you’ll probably want to provide a "t" just in case there is a network problem when Facebook tries to connect.

In all other cases, Facebook will use your:

```
<meta name="title" content="your title" />
<meta name="description" content="your content" />
```

for thumb

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
```

now ok?

Comment: @Filip Krstic No, my issue is that I want to assign my own description and not the page title...

Comment: @Patrick, if you want to make it multiple, for example for news on your site, if I you, I`ll do it on this way. 
I`ll make php function which generate html page for each news, and on that each html page, I`ll put this three tags of code in <head></head> section.
Creating html pages for each news also is very good for SEO.

Comment: @Filip Krstic But I don't want to have multiple pages... all my projects are in a list on the same page

Comment: They will be in list on same page, you will export it from mysql_db or whatever. Your site will work normally, as you wish. With that function you will have your projects on two palaces. For your site you export projects from mysql, and for SEO and Facebook etc, you can use that html pages. If you interested in, I can write that function for you, and take a look, make decision.

Comment: @Filip Krstic I have individual pages for each project ready since I'm using a CMS. However if I do as you suggest, when someone is clicking on the link on Facebook is redirected to the single pages and on the main page list.

Comment: @Patrick If you want to publish on Facebook one project, and when someone clicks on it to appear in a list of projects, I think that this is not possible. See the Facebook connect (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/183/)
The difference is if you want to publish something on Facebook, if you want every visitor who views the project on your site, publish it to his Facebook profile.

Comment: @Filip Krstic I want to assign my description to the shared material on facebook. If Facebook only allows to post the title of html page, then there is nothing I can do.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, you asked how to change the page title http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL&t=TITLE

On your page, where you want to add facebook link, you can use:

```
<head>
<title>your title</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL&t=TITLE" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.example.com/exampleimage.jpg" /></a>
</body>
```

and "your title" title, will appear.

When someone click on that link, browser redirect him to  http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL&t=TITLE page, and he isn't more on your web site. You can't change layout of facebook page, also can't change facebook title and others.

Only what you can do is to delete &t=TITLE. In this case:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.example.com/exampleimage.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: What I'm saying is that the parameter &t=TITLE doesn't work. Try by yourself. Facebook override it.

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what is needed to generate these buttons automatically and easily http://www.latestseotools.com/tools/socialbuttons-generator/